# NCurses Refresh

Tags: c, ncurses

I have a small ncurse program I'm running, but the output doesn't seem to show up unless I stick the `wrefresh()` in a while loop.

Is there some buffering going on or something? I tried other `refresh` functions in the library and `fflush` with `stddout` (which I don't think makes sense, but worth a try), but nothing seems to work.

A second small question: to make `getch()` non-blocking we need to call `nodelay(win,TRUE)`, right?

```
void main()
{
        initscr();
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW,COLOR_CYAN);
        WINDOW *win = newwin(10,10,1,1);
        wbkgd(win,COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wprintw(win,"Hello, World.");
        wrefresh(win);
        getch();
        delwin(win);
        endwin();
}
```

Comment: I added the following code: 

while(ERR == getch()) {
     wrefresh(win);
     ++ctr;
}

and the output looks good, but I still don't understand why it doesn't initially display without looping.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not supposed to mix operations on `stdscr` and windows created with `newwin()`.  `getch()` operates on `stdscr`, so that is your problem.  Replace that call with

```
wgetch(win);
```

(`getch()` is causing `stdscr` to be dumped over the top of your other window, and because that happens so quickly it looks like the other window never got displayed at all).

Comment: Right you are. Thanks a bunch! Sorry, but I need to ask one more: when you call a function that operates on a window does it set focus to that window if there is such a thing as focus?

Comment: @Tim: The hardware cursor is left at the location of the cursor in the window that you last refreshed, but that's really the only kind of "focus".

Comment: If you need independent overlaping windows you should look at the panels library that is part of ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

That's working as designed.  That allows you to completely redraw your next screen but only the parts that actually changed get sent to the terminal at refresh time.  This isn't such a big deal these days but made a big difference when terminal connections were relatively slow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that's the case, but I don't see anything but a blank screen. How do I get the window and text to appear *initially* without repeatedly calling wrefresh()?