# ncurses.h, wprintw doesn't work, even after refresh

Tags: c, window, ncurses

I'm using the library ncurses, and when I try to call `wprintw()`, and then do a `wrefresh` on the right window, it doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW *winTest; //The window
    int rows, cols; //Rows and colums in the terminal

    initscr(); //Starting NCurses
    raw(); //Calling 'getch()' doesn't wait for '\n' 
    noecho(); //Doesn't print what's written by user
    curs_set(0); //Doesn't display the cursor

    getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols); //How many rows and colums in stdscr (the terminal)

    winTest = newwin(10, 10, rows/2, cols/2); //Creates a square WINDOW at the center of the terminal

    mvwprintw(winTest, 0, 0, "Test"); //Prints "Test" on the created window

    wrefresh(winTest); //Refreshes so what's done is displayed
    getch(); //Pause

    delwin(winTest); //Free the memory for winTest
    endwin(); //Ends NCurses
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this, nothing is displayed.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I compile with gcc:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wformat -o test.exe test.c -lncurses
```

and I execute in the gnome-terminal.

Comment: Seeing you hide all the compiler errors is not a good sign. Remove this stuff: `-Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wformat` the compiler might tell you something important.

Comment: @TonyRuth: you're aware that these flags enable *additional* warnings (and also make them fatal)?

Comment: @TonyRuth ehem... that's enabling all compiler errors, not hiding them.

Comment: Ah, you're right, sorry.

Comment: I replaced the second pause, `getch()` with my own pause function: `scanf("%*s");` and then it displayed test in the middle like it was supposed to. I think what was happening is it went through both pauses in one go so that you never saw the "Test" because it was deleted as fast as it was created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NCurses Refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808626/ncurses-refresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808626/ncurses-refresh/3808913#3808913), you should replace:

```
getch();
```

by:

```
wgetch(winTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I replaced the second pause, getch() with my own pause function: scanf("%*s"); and then it displayed test in the middle like it was supposed to. I think what was happening is it went through both pauses in one go so that you never saw the "Test" because it was deleted as fast as it was created. – Tony Ruth

Thanks to Tony Ruth, who answered my question. Even if I still don't understand why `getch()` erases what's written, replacing it with `scanf("%*s")` works fine !

PS: Don't know how to tell this issue is solved :/

EDIT : You can also call 'wgetch(aWindow)' on whatever window, and every windows will be corectly displayed :) (Thank to Ruud, who told it)